Is this roofing company trying to scam?
So a friend had a roofing company come by a couple months after hail hit area.   They checked roof and there was damage.
Insurance company came out and they verified damage and itemized the work needed.    They then sent friend a check for the prorated price of the roof minus deductible.   For the question let's imagine that the roof was 30k but prorated to 15k because of age and deductible was 5k.    So insurance sent a 10k check.
Roofing company (not a small company and good reviews) says that give them the 10k check, they will buy materials and schedule a date.
Here is where I couldn't help because of my lack of knowledge of the process.   The roofing company says that once the job is completed the insurance company will issue another check for 15k (they had a legal/insurance name for this).   So when job ends they will have the 10k down payment, 15k more from insurance company, and $5k out of pocket from friend.
However...   there is no statement of work other than authorization of the roofing company to work with the insurance company and work off there itemized list.    There is no proof that the insurance company will pay the additional 15k.   There is also several items (small equating to 2k) that won't be done and there is no proof what the final payout would be.    Is this just the way insurance claims work or is asking for a work order and list of responsibilities (roofer getting 15k from insurance) plus the itemized payouts of what they are not doing... this just normal business or scam?

Where in the world are you? Insurance laws and norms differ around the world and this is an international site.

Midwest US.................

Why would they expect another $15K from the insurance? Everything else is OK, replacing a roof for $30K is not unheard of, but this point is just weird to me.

@littleadv - that is the whole reason for the question....

A 30% deposit is too much. If the roofer needs $10k for materials before even starting, that is a red flag.

@blankip, please feel free to come back and update the question when your friend has the issue resolved for others to learn from.

Yes this was a scam but not in the sense of the roofing company trying to commit outright fraud.
What the roofing company was doing was using the principle of recoverable depreciation to get people to pay them for a new roof.   I don't want to get into explaining what this is but basically it allows the owner to get their whole roof paid for no matter its age.    Without this concept you get a prorated amount - discussed in the question.
Note that most insurance companies have been phasing out policies or making them cost a ton with this concept...
So I will label this a scam.    Roofing company comes out and says we will work with insurance company and replace your roof for basically the cost of your deductible.    They go over in detail how you will recover your money (recoverable depreciation) after the work is done.   And this is the hard part for consumers - recoverable depreciation is real, is not part of most current contracts and is only recoverable once ALL of the work is verified done.
The roofing company is scamming because they know most of their customers will never get that money and probably wouldn't decide to replace roof if they knew they weren't getting it.    They are setting up a scenario where the owner is arguing age of roof (very hard to prove if you weren't the owner who replaced it) or the policy info.   Most home owners will lose.    Most home owners will pay thousands extra (10k in this case) and roofer knows once they get the original funds there is no turning back...
For this particular roofing company the scam is they will not put any payment details in writing.   I told friend to have the itemize who would pay what.   And they wouldn't because they knew the insurance company would never pay the last payment.

Yes the roofing company is trying to cheat you.
From everything you've said the insurance company considers that a 10k cheque is the total payment they will be making for your roof. 30k replacement cost, halved because it's halfway through its life and minus the 5k deductible is absolutely the normal calculation insurance companies make. They will not be paying you or a roofing company any more money. The roofing company is trying to con you by making you think insurance will cover all their costs when they won't. There is also no reason why they want a cheque made out to you. It might be a good idea to call the insurance company and check on what I said, because companies can do things differently.
The other scammy part is that the roofing company hasn't given you a statement of work and a firm quote for it. You should absolutely never give a worker or company any money until they have given you a firm price, including exactly what work you will get for that price. Only then can you know what you are signing up for. Without that in writing you could find yourself owing them more than the 30k you think, or paying 30K for them doing almost nothing. And 10K is too high for a deposit on a 30K job.
Either of those two cheats is reason enough to avoid that company. Consider reporting them to the better business bureau.
Instead cash the cheque. Then get two or better still three other reputable companies to quote for a roof replacement, or for repairs if you want to go that way. Get a detailed statement of work and a firm price. Expect the replacement prices to be about 30k. Tell them insurance has already given you a settlement and so effectively you are paying yourself. That should make them keep the price low.

The roofing company can say whatever they want to, but the one thing they can't do is make promises about what the insurance company will do in the future.
After the work is done it will be up to the homeowner to pay them. But there is no obligation between the insurance company and the roofing company; there is no contract between them.
If the insurance company has written a check to compensate for damages they might consider the matter closed, or they might have written that check as an estimate towards the total cost and they will make up the difference once a total bill is presented. Your friend needs to talk with their insurance company to find this out.
A reputable roofing company should have no problem dealing directly with the insurance company to get paid, and certainly the insurance company knows how to do it. I would let my insurance agent earn their commission by calling her up and admitting to her that I need her help, and could she please have her office handle this for me? They do this every week, so why not use their experience?
At the minimum, before giving any money to the roofing company ask them for a written contract. This contract should show clearly the cost of materials and labor, along with the expectation of payment: how much of a deposit upfront and when the balance will be due once work is complete.
Then I would ask at least two other reputable roofers for a bid with the same conditions. Maybe my insurance agent might have companies they have worked well with and could recommend.
Oh, and the deposit will be paid for by credit card, even if I had to pay a credit card fee (maybe 3%) for this. The Internet is full of tales of woe of contractors getting paid up front and vanishing before or during the work. Paying the balance after the work is done is a different story; there's no need to pay a credit card fee for that.

"but the one thing they can't do is make promises about what the insurance company will do in the future." - They can make such a promise if they want, but they'd be on the hook if the promise was broken.  The normal way to make such a promise would be to include in their contract that the roofer will eat the cost if the insurance company refuses to pay.  Mind you, nobody actually does this.

The roofer can make promises, but there's no way they would agree in writing to do work they think they might not get paid for. There are so many ways this could go bad and all of them end up with the homeowner holding the bag. Bottom line: a contract is the best way forward.


Insurance company came out and they verified damage and itemized the
work needed. They then sent friend a check for the prorated price of
the roof minus deductible. For the question let's imagine that the
roof was 30k but prorated to 15k because of age and deductible was 5k.
So insurance sent a 10k check.
Roofing company (not a small company and good reviews) says that give
them the 10k check, they will buy materials and schedule a date.
Here is where I couldn't help because of my lack of knowledge of the
process. The roofing company says that once the job is completed the
insurance company will issue another check for 15k (they had a
legal/insurance name for this). So when job ends they will have the
10k down payment, 15k more from insurance company, and $5k out of
pocket from friend.

The insurance company said we agree the roof will cost $30K to replace; but because it was some years old we will only pay $15K minus the $5K deductible.
That means that the roofing company expect $10K from the insurance company and $20K from your fiend.
This verges on being a scam because they may be counting on your friend misunderstanding, or they may have been clear but your friend is misunderstanding.
The insurance company is avoiding the situation where they pay full price for a roof when it was at end-of-life. The roofer wants to get the full price. The insurance company expects the homeowner to pay the difference.
Additional thoughts:

If there is a mortgage company involved they will require the repairs to be made. They want to protect their investment. Frequently the checks will be made out jointly to the homeowner and the lender, this requires their cooperation to cash the check. The lender will generally want to see proof of the repair being made before allowing the check to be cashed.

The idea of keeping the money and skipping the repair can cause issues later. If the roof leaks and cause additional damage, the insurer may determine that the additional damage won't be covered because if the repair had been made the additional damage would not have occurred.


